# Weird Isotope.js Animation when filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

When I am setting up this filter and using it, the functionality works except for one thing. There is a weird animation during the filter process.

[In my codepen](http://codepen.io/ishio/pen/JNmQrr) the code works great. Copied and pasted with the same JS version and the same build version.

[In my website](http://freydesign.staging.wpengine.com/blog/) it does not work. Now I've gone through and disabled all plugins and every script that is being called besides my code, which was placed in an isolated .js file, and the CSS files.

I am not sure what exactly the issue is anymore and can't figure out how to isolate the issue further to identify the problem.

I am running the website on WordPress, version 4.7.5

Below is my javascript. It's the only thing I am calling.

```
(function($){
  'use strict';

    var grid = jQuery('.masonry').isotope(),
        $win = jQuery(window);

    jQuery('.filter span a').click(function(){
    jQuery( this ).parents( 'div.filter' ).find( 'span a' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    jQuery( this ).addClass( 'active' );

    grid.isotope({
      filter: jQuery(this).attr('data-filter'),
      layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: You have an error in console: *«Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null»* This is because you try to initiate a Google Map on an inexistant element `#map-canvas`... So fix that... Maybe this is the problem since the `script.js` file probablty stopped loading right there.

Comment: Yep. What Louys said check if element exists (  length() )

Comment: Is this related to the animation issue I am talking about???

Comment: After moving the map to a separate file, calling to it only on one page, both the map is broken and the animation issue still persists. If the issue was the Uncaught TypeError, i fear the filtering wouldn't work at all. I even went to isolate the issue by putting it into the template.php file

Comment: i answered this below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<link rel='stylesheet' id='isotope-style-css' ...>` CSS.

Unless you specify that you are only using CSS ([see animationEngine in the Metafizzy docs](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/animating.html)) then it's going to load both the jQuery animation and the CSS -- causing the weirdness. You can test out this fact by checking out your CodePen duplicated here with the weirdness because I added the CSS: http://codepen.io/carasmo/pen/KmrPRb

Comment: God, such little things I over look. Thank you so much!

Comment: Isotope v3 does not contain or use any CSS, only the js. The isotope CSS is from isotope  v1. I'm fairly certain `animationengine` is deprecated in v3

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in console: *«Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null»*.

This is because you try to initiate a Google Map on an inexistant element `#map-canvas`.

**To fix that...** What I would do is to remove lines #881 to #1183, which is your Google Map API initialisation script, from the [script.js](http://freydesign.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/frey-v2/files/js/script.js?ver=1.0).

I would place this in a map.js which I would call only on the page(s) where there actually is an element with id `map-canvas`.

For now, this error just halts the loading of script.js.
So the `document.ready()` function isn't closed properly.

*You used `(function($){` which is the same as `document.ready()` on line #209.*

Comment: oh jeez, how did I miss this! Thank you. This website is a disaster. I am a dev who was asked to rebuild this, but keep everything as it was in place. Thank you

Comment: After doing this, nothing has changed.

Comment: I even went to isolate the issue by putting it into the template.php file

Comment: Okay... So this is not the reason. But it was a good thing to try. Now I think you use Isotope **AND** Masonry on those blog posts... Right?

Comment: No, just Isotope. It seems masonry is automatically called. In the codepen, the scripts called are jquery and the isotope script.

Comment: mmm... I'm on class `active` now... It is also used by your carousel in the header. Try to change all `active` classes for `active-isotope` in CSS and JS.

Comment: Changed the class name from `active` to `current` That also wasn't the issue

Comment: Try removing the function `function reorganizeIsotope()`... to see what it does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144696/discussion-between-ishio-and-louys-patrice-bessette).